# Install Ubuntu on HP TM2, BUG: soft lockup - CPU stuck for 23s!

Tags: boot, hp

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP TM2, which by the way has about 6 years or so, and a second battery. Previously it had installed Linux Mint as well as some older Ubuntu versions around 10 or 11. Some newest Ubuntu versions however cause problems during install.

After plugging USB with Ubuntu 16.04 and selecting boot from USB I see a logo then black text screen saying repeatedly something like following, seemingly in endless loop:

> BUG: soft lockup - CPU stuck for 23s!

I am not sure what to do. There is one [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205211) where power supply seems to have been the problem but I dont want to buy one. Please suggest some workaround to get some Ubuntu installed. I will report later if older Ubuntu can get installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazingly, I just hard rebooted and at second attempt installation went just fine. Now that Ubuntu is installed, I still occasionally get that weird lockup. I just restart it till it kicks in.